# Aggregation of character column grop by and paste

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, aggregate

I have the next dataframe:

```
col1<-c("A1","B1","A1","B1","C1","C1","A1")
col2<-c("a","b","c","d","b","f","a")
dat<-data.frame(col1,col2)
```

From the previous data frame I would like to get something like this:

```
A1   "ac"
B1   "bd" 
C1   "bf"
```

I mean, I need to aggregate by paste unique values in col 2 grouping the codes in col1.

I was trying something like this

```
   dat%>%group_by(col1)%>%summarise(pp=paste0(col2))
```

but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on the `unique` rows.  Also, `paste0` by itself doesn't work.  it needs the additional argument `collapse`

```
 aggregate(col2~ col1, unique(dat), FUN = paste, collapse="")
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>%
   distinct %>%
   group_by(col1) %>%
   summarise(pp = str_c(col2, collapse=""), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  col1  pp   
  <chr> <chr>
1 A1    ac   
2 B1    bd   
3 C1    bf
```